# add a rich-text(tinymce) content into the body of the mail when using mailto?

Tags: email, character-encoding, html-email, mailto

I want to put some content(rich-text content) into email body using mailto function, but user can not see the HTML entity on content they can only see formatted plain text.

My content contains some HTML entity so i use `HTML ENCODING`. But when i see my email, it's body it contains all HTML characters as it is. I don't want this because i want user can see only formatted plain text in email body.

For Example: -  I have some content like this -

`<h1 style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 25px;>Hello</h1>` in my content and i put this content into `mailto` body section into link `href`.

I want when use click on `mailto` link and email is open, body contains only formatted HTML header like - **Hello**, so the user can see only bold header `Hello` in email content

Can any one please tell me how can i do this?

Thank you..!!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice but.. it's not possible. The mail generated from a mailto link is PLAIN/TEXT.

REFERENCE:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368